# SQL : Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have met a very strange problem. There are two sql queries:

Q1:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TargetID
             FROM tbl_2 
             WHERE PeopleID = 'AAA') 
AND ID = 49
```

Q2:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TargetID
             FROM tbl_2 
             WHERE PeopleID = 'BBB') 
AND ID = 49
```

We could find these two queries are identical except for **PeopleID**. But their result were very difference. For Q1, we got "**Error converting data type varchar to numeric**"; And for Q2, it ran well. I was confused!

There are some infomation that may be useful.

```
tbl_1  ID       numeric(18,0) not null

tbl_2  TargetID varchar(50)   not null
```

and every **TargetID** in Q1 or Q2 could pass the `IsNumeric` test (namely, `IsNumeric(TargetID) = 1`)

another information: if we comment the line `AND ID = 49` and every query run well

thx for your help

Comment: why do you have a numeric in a varchar(50) datatype?

Comment: this table is created by other people not me. and for some reason I have to use it. :)

Answer (score 2):

i would try doing something like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_1
WHERE convert(varchar(50), ID) IN (SELECT TargetID
             FROM tbl_2 
             WHERE PeopleID = 'BBB') 
AND ID = 49
```

since the ID is converted to a varchar, it should work ok.

Comment: thank you. I have tried this before, it does work. But I want to know more and want to know what causes the difference. :)

Comment: Be aware that if there is an index in tbl_1.ID it can no longer be used by this query due to the convert.  For example, google [sargs sql server search argument]

Answer (score 0):

How about using EXISTS?

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM tbl_2 
             WHERE PeopleID = 'BBB'
             AND tbl_2.TargetID = tbl_1.ID) 
AND ID = 49
```

Comment: sorry, it can't work. Q1 return the same error, and Q2 work well.

Answer (score 0):

@Vincent have you checked if there is a space type character (or currency characters) before or after the TargetID when PeopleID = 'BBB'?
You will get this error message if there's a Tab or CrLf etc before or after the TargetID. A regular whitespace however shouldn't give an error.

Comment: Note that IsNumeric() will also return true for some non-numeric characters. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql),